If f is lebesgue integrable then |f| is lebesgue integrable?

In the book "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms - A Unified Approach, 5th Edition" by J. H. Hubbard and B. B. Hubbard, the lebesgue integral of $f$ is defined if there exists an infinite sequence of R-integrable functions such that the sum of the series of integrals of the absolute values converges and the sum of the series of the functions equals $f$ almost everywhere. Then the lebesgue integral is defined to be the sum of the series of the integrals of the functions, as shown in definition 4.11.8.
A few pages later (with the only other theorem being mentioned is that if $f$ is R-integrable then it is L-integrable), the authors mention that "By our definition, $f$ is L-integrable implies $|f|$ is L-integrable" and I do not see how that follows. The only way that makes sense to me is if all the functions in the sequence of R-integrable functions have no overlap in their supports. So can anyone explain how it can be shown that $f$ L-integrable implies $|f|$ L-integrable, by the approach in the book?
This is where they say it, by the way:
EDIT: So we need a sequence of R-integrable functions $h_k$ such that $$|f| = \left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \right| = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h_k.\tag{1}$$ Well, if we tried a telescoping sum (as suggested by @s.harp) like the following: $$h_k = \left| \sum_{i=0}^k f_i \right| - \left| \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f_i \right|\tag{2}$$ then we would have that $$h_k \leq \left| \sum_{i=0}^{k} f_i - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f_i \right| = \left| f_k \right|.\tag{3}$$ We also have that $h_k$ are R-integrable because the sum of R-integrable functions are R-integrable and the absolute value of an R-integrable function is R-integrable. Thus $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h_k(\textbf{x})| |d^n \textbf{x}| \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f_k(\textbf{x})| |d^n \textbf{x}| < \infty \tag{4}$$ and $$\left| \sum_{k=0}^{N} f_k \right| = \sum_{k=0}^{N} h_k \tag{5}$$ so $$|f| = \left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \right| =_L \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h_k \tag{6}$$ thus $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(\textbf{x})| |d^n \textbf{x}| = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h_k(\textbf{x}) |d^n \textbf{x}| \tag{7}$$
EDIT 2: Now I'm not sure how to establish that if we can find one sequence of R-integrable functions, $f_k$, ( the sum of which converges to $f$ almost everywhere) such that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f_k|(\textbf{x}) |d^n \textbf{x}| = \infty$, i.e. the series of integrals of absolute values diverges, then any other sequence $g_k$, for which the sum converges to $f$ almost everywhere, must also have a divergent series of integrals of absolute values: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|g_k|(\textbf{x}) |d^n \textbf{x}| = \infty$

I’m guessing that here R integrable denotes Riemann integrable? If so this is an awfully strange way of constructing the Lesbesgue  integral.

Usually the Lebesgue integral of $f$ existing and $f$ being Lebesgue integrable are slightly different notions (the latter one having a finite integral). What definition do you have for the latter?

It’s not as immediate as with other definitions, but it should follow from considering a telescoping sum expression.

@Lorago I don't think the book gives a definition of lebesgue integrable. Everything you see in the image is all the theory they have (on Lebesgue integration) until they make the seemingly matter-of-fact statement that if f is L-integrable then |f| is L-integrable. The authors do mention that this approach is non-standard so it's hard to find more information about it.

@s.harp I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate a bit?

@s.harp do you perhaps mean let $h_k = \left| \sum_{i=1}^k f_i \right| - \left| \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} f_i \right|$

It does follow from the definition, namely the last definition you included, but the proof isn't immediate, I would say. $f=\sum_k f_k$ being $L$-integrable immediately implies that $g=\sum_k|f_k|$ is $L$-integrable, since by definition the requirement for $f$ and $g$ are literally the same ($||f_k|| = |f_k|$).
Then you may argue that you can indeed write any such sum $\sum_kf_k$ as a sum over $R$-integrable functions with disjoint supports (a.e.), and in that setting you will get $g=|f|$ a.e., completing the proof.

As a sidenote, it seems that the difficulty of this problem stems from this non-standard (and to me, impractical) approach to Lebesgue integrability. In my view, positive functions should be the easiest to integrate, and in all standard textbooks I believe the integrability of $|f|$ does follow immediately.

@SomeCallMeTim how can you establish that the $f_k$ have disjoint supports? Also, I'm wondering about the claim in the second image I posted where they concluded that |sin(x)/x| is not L-integrable simply because they found one sequence (the sum of which converges to |sin(x)/x|) that doesn't have a convergent series of integrals. Is it not possible to have another sequence (whose sum converges to |sin(x)/x|) that does have a convergent series of integrals?

@JohnDoe almost that, what you wrote may not be a summable sequence. But you can fix this by taking the difference of the sum of a(k) elements and a(k-1) elements (instead of k and k-1 as you wrote) where a is a rapidly increasing function ( I can’t write the formulas since I am travelling)

@JohnDoe For your second question, the answer is no. If two sequences converges to the same function, their series of integrals must agree - this is what should have been covered in Theorem $4.11.7$, but here they of course assume convergence first, which is a problem. You could prove it using monotonicity and the integrability of the absolute value of integrable functions, but this is of course the question of contention here.
I'll sketch how to fix supports in an answer.

It turns out my idea for converting to a series with disjoint support was hopelessly technical. For a better approach, I would check out Schilling's Measures, Integrals and Martingales, in particular chapters $7-9$ if I remember correctly.

@SomeCallMeTim Could you explain how to prove that the series of integrals of absolute values must agree if the series of the two sequences converge almost everywhere?

@JohnDoe Again, all my intuition and methods are based on a different approach than yours, and I fear my solution would be needlessly complicated and not in the spirit of Hubbard-Hubbard. I hope you can find assistance elsewhere.
